# To change text label to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replace the text label with a hyperlink when user select a checkbox one at a time.
Right now, one is checked, the rest change as well.  Would it be posible if the name remains the same for all input?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is not working correctly.

**CSS:**

```
.link { display: none }
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('input#chkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#clink').show();
        $('#label').hide();
    } else {
        $('#label').show();
        $('#clink').hide();
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<label>
    <input type="chkbox" name="item"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ value="1"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​/>
    <span id="label">SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="chkbox" name="item"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ value="2"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​/>
    <span id="label">SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="chkbox" name="item"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ value="3"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​/>
    <span id="label">SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="chkbox" name="item"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ value="4"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​/>
    <span id="label">SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
```

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: you have so many issues up there!!! 1- chkbox is not an input type 2- clink is not an ID (neither a tag if that what you mean!)  and so many other issues !!

Comment: Sorry copy/paste and removed unnecessary attributes in a hurry before submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with CSS, no need for javascript.

Now to point out your errors:

- `type="chkbox"` should be `type="checkbox"`
- Id must be unique on the page, if you need multiples, use class instead.

Now for the code:

```css
.link {display:none;}
label input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span {display:none;}
label input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ a {display:inline;}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1"/>
    <span>SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="2"/>
    <span >SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="3"/>
    <span >SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="4"/>
    <span >SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
```

If you want to continue with jQuery you can use the same html with the following

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
 //Get Siblings and toggle their visibility;
  $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
 //Get Siblings and toggle their visibility;
  $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

```css
.link {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1"/>
    <span>SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="2"/>
    <span >SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="3"/>
    <span >SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="4"/>
    <span >SELECT TO COMPARE</span>
    <a class="link" href="#">COMPARE</a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

The #chkbox in your code is an id selector, so you have to define an id attribute to use the '#' symbol

Also, please note that id must be unique for each page
https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/